# How to track CodePush release version on Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, code-push, react-native-code-push

I've just added CodePush to a react native project. I'm using Firebase Crashlytics for crash monitoring. I tried to look for a way to add the codepush release version to the crashlytics tracking, but couldn't find any. So how to add the codepush version to the crashlytics crash data?

Answer (score 0):

Found out it's possible to track it by setting custom attributes for crashlytics reports, like this:

`crashlytics().setAttribute('codePushVersion', 'v3')`